# How to keep the information of the confidence interval in the predictive step?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, poisson-distribution, bayesian, confidence-interval

Suppose I have a sample $X_1,X_2,...X_n$. Each $X_{i}$ comes from a poisson distribution $X_i \sim Po(\lambda)$. The unknown paremeter $\lambda$ is inferred using the next confidence interval :  $\lambda^{\pm} = \overline{X} \pm t^* \frac{\overline{X}}{\sqrt{n}}$ where $\lambda^+$ is the upper bound and $\lambda^-$ is the lower bound, $t^*$ is the confidence expressed over t-student distribution.

I have two questions. The second question is actually the question I ask, the first is only to check my reasoning is right.

First: Taking into account the data come from Poisson distribution and taking into account the Central Limit Theorem, is it right the inference a did?It means: is it right to use the t-student approach? Or is it another better way to do?

Second: (That's the main question):

As I don't know the $\lambda$ parameter, I inferred it using confident intervals. Now I want to carry out some predictions of future events and calculate the associated probabilities, it means I wanto to know: $prob\{X_{n+1} = K\}$. To do this: What number in the interval $[\lambda^-,\lambda^+]$ I should take? Obviously, maximize the likelihood is the best option, so I would take $\overline{X}$. So the question is:

Is there a way to take into account the uncertainty in the probabilities of the prediction? or: Is there a way to keep the knowledge of the confident interval in the probabilities of the new prediction? or: At the moment in that you use an only number(point estimation), how to keep the uncertainty information?

To be clearer take into account these two examples. The same process but with two different interval confidence:

1) $[\lambda^-, \lambda^+] = [6, 8]$, $\overline{X} = 7 \rightarrow X_{n+1}\sim Po(\lambda = \overline{X}) \rightarrow Prob\{X_{n+1} = 6\} = 0.449$

2) $[\lambda^-, \lambda^+] = [1, 13]$, $\overline{X} = 7 \rightarrow X_{n+1}\sim Po(\lambda = \overline{X}) \rightarrow Prob\{X_{n+1} = 6\} = 0.449$

The first contain less uncertainty than the second, so how could I maintain the information of confident interval?

I hope I was clear in the question.

Lot of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental question seems to be how to find a confidence interval for
$\lambda$ given $n$ independent counts $X_i$ from $\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda).$
In that case $T = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim \mathsf{Pois}(n\lambda).$

I don't understand your interval because the margin of error seems to
use an estimate of *variance* (divided by $\sqrt{n}$) rather of the standard deviation. And
I don't see how a t distribution is appropriate.

You can get a good confidence interval for $n\lambda$ from
$T + 2 \pm 1.96\sqrt{T + 1}.$ Then divide the endpoints by $n$ to
get a confidence interval for $\lambda.$

Another good way to get an interval estimate for $\lambda$ is to use
a Bayesian procedure. You can use a relatively noninformative gamma
prior if you have no useful prior information. If you are trying to use the estimate of $\lambda$ to predict
future behavior of the same  process, then a Bayesian approach may be preferable.

Comment: After reading your answer I realized that I didn't be aware that the sum of poisson variables also come from a Poisson distribution of n*lambda. The intervals that I wrote are only an example to emphasize that I want to keep the uncertainty in future predictions. So in the first example I have more uncertainty than in the second, but when I going to use the parameter to do future predictions, this uncertainty is not used. The batesian approach take into account this uncertainty, but how the classical approach take into account? thanks !